# Unicode Issue Pdf while adding digital signature

Tags: pdf, certificate, adobe, digital-signature

i have an issue regarding signing PDF file using digital signature certificate coming from Smart Card 
all signatures have appearance without unicode as the following
[![All Signatures][1]][1]

and when i select the signature it coming like below without unicode too
[image]

and after signing the document it still the same ,

[image]

kindly note that the Certificate issuer name is in arabic language so please how to fix it 
thank you very much .

Comment: Your first image vanished.

Comment: That been said, as the dialogs you show are not related to iTextSharp but seem to be Adobe Reader dialogs, you either have found an issue in Adobe Reader or (which is more likely) in your certificate. If you share your certificate (merely the public certificate, nor the private key!), we can inspect it and tell where the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to how the Arabic name is encoded in the certificate.

---

In the certificate in question the name in Arabic script is contained in the `subjectAltName` extension and it is encoded as a `TeletexString`:

```
032F   75:         SEQUENCE {
    <06 03>
0331    3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER subjectAltName (2 5 29 17)
         :             (X.509 extension)
    <04 6E>
0336   6E:           OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
    <30 6C>
0338   6C:             SEQUENCE {
    <A4 4A>
033A   4A:               [4] {
    <30 48>
033C   48:                 SEQUENCE {
    <31 46>
033E   46:                   SET {
    <30 44>
0340   44:                     SEQUENCE {
    <06 03>
0342    3:                       OBJECT IDENTIFIER commonName (2 5 4 3)
         :                         (X.520 DN component)
    <14 3D>
0347   3D:                       TeletexString
         :                   'Ù.Ø­Ù.Ø¯ Ø§Ù.Ø¨Ø¯Ø±Ø§Ù.Ù. Ø¹Ø¨Ø¯Ø§Ù.Ø¹Ø²Ù.Ø² Ø§Ù'
         :                   '.Ø¨Ø¯Ø±Ø§Ù.Ù.'
         :                       }
         :                     }
         :                   }
         :                 }
    <81 1E>
0386   1E:               [1] 'XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX'
         :               }
         :             }
         :           }
```

(As the OP redacted the email address in his screenshots, I did the same here.)

A `TeletexString` (= `T61String`) type in ASN.1

> denotes an arbtrary string of T.61 characters. T.61 is an eight-bit extension to the ASCII character set. Special "escape" sequences specify the interpretation of subsequent character values as, for example, Japanese; the initial interpretation is Latin. The character set includes non-printing control characters. **The T61String type allows only the Latin and Japanese character interepretations, and implementors' agreements for directory names exclude control characters [NIST92].** A T61String value can have any length, including zero. This type is a string type.
>
> *([A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html))*

Thus, while T.61 *does* generically allow Arabic script, its use in the `TeletexString` (= `T61String`) type in ASN.1 *does **not.***

(You can find the exact definition of allowed characters in [ISO/IEC 8824-1](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c068350_ISO_IEC_8824-1_2015.zip) in combination with [the ISO International Register of Coded Character Sets to be used with Escape Sequences](https://www.itscj.ipsj.or.jp/itscj_english/iso-ir/ISO-IR.pdf).)

As usual, some applications have a `TeletexString` implementation which exactly covers the specified extend and some have implementations that covers more, up to the whole T.61 character set.

Adobe Reader in particular seems to be among the former, at least it does not cover the Arabic script in your `subjectAltName`. The certificate viewer of Microsoft Windows, on the other hand, is among the latter, in particular it does cover your `subjectAltName`.

That been said, the use of `TeletexString` in this context is questionable anyways, according to RFC 5280:

> Implementations may encounter certificates and CRLs with
>      names encoded using TeletexString, BMPString, or UniversalString, but
>      **support for these is OPTIONAL.**

Thus, you actually can be happy that your certificate is accepted at all as Adobe could as well have chosen not to support `TeletexString` at all anymore and reject your certificate for that reason...

---

To get a more universal acceptance (by RFC compliant software) of the Arabic script in your `subjectAltName`, you should try and persuade your certificate authority to re-issue your certificate but use `UTF8String` for Arabic script instead of `TeletexString`. There may be some broken legacy applications, though, that hickup with such a corrected certificate...

Comment: That was excellent answer , thank you mkl , i will try to reproduce another certificate and try , at least we know that part of the issue is depending on the certificate encoding .